# I Need an arabic quote from fath al bari

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I am looking for the original explanation by Ibn Hajr of a hadith in Sahih al-Bukhari in which he says the following (translation):

> Hafiz Ibn al-Hajr al-Asqalani says in his Fath al Bari , (in vol.4 ,
>   book of hire/ijara, page 448-449) commenting on these two narrations:
>   “and it is evident ( from these stated narrations) that the lasting of
>   this Islamic nation is somewhat a thousand years, this is because the
>   age of the Jewish nation is equivalent to that of the time periods of
>   the Christian and Muslim ages combined, and the people of transmission
>   (ahl an naql) have agreed that the period of the Jews till the advent
>   of Allah’s final Apostle Muhammad was more than 2000 years, and the
>   span of the age of the Christians was 600 years from them. And also
>   this narration points the fact about how little of the age of this
>   world has remained.”

Comment: Why the downvotes and close votes people?

Comment: Given that the book and page number are clearly present in the quote itself, is the original text really all you're looking for?  The question would probably be better worked as asking how accurate (or encompassing) this particular *translation* is.

Comment: Im working on references for something i am writing that is why i need it, and yes it is accurate as some scholars have quoted it. Imam bukhari records this hadith six times in his sahih i only need the tafsir for one and wasn't certain which one or where to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the bottom of [this](http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=4135&idto=4136&bk_no=52&ID=1431) page you will find what you are looking for specifically:

> واستدل به على أن بقاء هذه الأمة يزيد على الألف ؛ لأنه يقتضي أن مدة اليهود نظير مدتي النصارى والمسلمين ، وقد اتفق أهل النقل على أن مدة اليهود إلى بعثة النبي - صلى الله عليه وسلم - كانت أكثر من ألفي سنة ، ومدة النصارى من ذلك ستمائة ، وقيل : أقل ، فتكون مدة المسلمين أكثر من ألف قطع

The *sharh* is of [this](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/37/11) hadith:

> Narrated Abu Musa:
>
> The Prophet (saws) said, "The example of Muslims, Jews and Christians is like the example of a man who employed laborers to work for him from morning till night for specific wages. They worked till midday and then said, 'We do not need your money which you have fixed for us and let whatever we have done be annulled.' The man said to them, 'Don't quit the work, but complete the rest of it and take your full wages.' But they refused and went away. The man employed another batch after them and said to them, 'Complete the rest of the day and yours will be the wages I had fixed for the first batch.' So, they worked till the time of `Asr prayer. Then they said, "Let what we have done be annulled and keep the wages you have promised us for yourself.' The man said to them, 'Complete the rest of the work, as only a little of the day remains,' but they refused. Thereafter he employed another batch to work for the rest of the day and they worked for the rest of the day till the sunset, and they received the wages of the two former batches. So, that was the example of those people (Muslims) and the example of this light (guidance) which they have accepted willingly.

Comment: jazak allah brother for your held that is exactly what i am after, may allah reward you.